# Drool engine file not getting executed

Tags: java, xml, drools, rule-engine

I'm trying to execute following program however `timesheet.drl` file is not getting called and just giving o/p : Final timesheet status null
. Unable to find what's going wrong.

Resources : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POVe4QY_9p8

DroolDemoMain.Java

```
package com.sample;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

public class DroolDemoMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

          KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
          KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
          KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

          Timesheet timesheet = getTimesheetValues();
          kSession.insert(timesheet);
          kSession.fireAllRules();
          System.out.println("Final timesheet status "+ timesheet.getPayStatus());


    }
      catch(Throwable t) {  
          t.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

    private static Timesheet getTimesheetValues() {

        Timesheet timesheet = new Timesheet();
        timesheet.setEmployeeHours(5);
        timesheet.setProjectBudgetOk(true);
        timesheet.setOverlappingTimesheet(false);

        return timesheet;

    }
}
```

Timesheet.java

```
package com.sample;

public class Timesheet {

    private int employeeHours;
    private boolean projectBudgetOk;
    private boolean duplicateTimesheet;
    private boolean overlappingTimesheet;
    private String payStatus;

    public int getEmployeeHours() {
        return employeeHours;
    }
    public void setEmployeeHours(int employeeHours) {
        this.employeeHours = employeeHours;
    }
    public boolean isProjectBudgetOk() {
        return projectBudgetOk;
    }
    public void setProjectBudgetOk(boolean projectBudgetOk) {
        this.projectBudgetOk = projectBudgetOk;
    }
    public boolean isDuplicateTimesheet() {
        return duplicateTimesheet;
    }
    public void setDuplicateTimesheet(boolean duplicateTimesheet) {
        this.duplicateTimesheet = duplicateTimesheet;
    }
    public boolean isOverlappingTimesheet() {
        return overlappingTimesheet;
    }
    public void setOverlappingTimesheet(boolean overlappingTimesheet) {
        this.overlappingTimesheet = overlappingTimesheet;
    }
    public String getPayStatus() {
        return payStatus;
    }
    public void setPayStatus(String payStatus) {
        this.payStatus = payStatus;
    }

}
```

timesheet.drl

```
package com.sample
import com.sample.Timesheet;

rule"Hours Less"
 when
  timesheet:Timesheet(employeeHours<8)
 then
 System.out.println("Employee hours Less Payment Denied");
 timesheet.setPayStatus("Denied");
end
```

kmodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">

    <kbase name="rules" packages="rules">
        <ksession name="ksession-rules"/>
    </kbase>

</kmodule>
```

can anyone explain me what is going wrong with my code and what should do for the successful execution?

[Screenshot of the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSbLz.png)

Comment: What's the structure of your project? Where do you have your java classes, your `kmodule.xml` and your `.drl` file?

Comment: Hi,I have added the project structure image : 'enter image description here'.and you can check the packages and file name at the top of the code.I would be very thankful,please help me out :)

Comment: @ Esteban,is there any update on this issue?

Comment: The structure looks fine to me. Could you create a simple reproducer?

Comment: well,I'm not familiar with the reproducer.What can be done here?

Comment: Create a small, self-contained, project where this problem can be reproduced and share that with us.

Answer (score 0):

In your kmodule.xml, the packages value is wrong. It should match with the package you are giving int the drl file.

Comment: so what should I write?

Comment: Write packages=com.samples